# Testing system for teaching

Tags: survey

I tried find testing system, that allow tests students, but unable to find any that fits some requirements.

For example all services allow at top randomize order of predefined options.

But I need, for example, have ability fill some category with 100 of correct answers and with 900 of wrong answers. After that system generate several questions for category, some wrong, some correct, or no correct at all. And different students, or same student at each try have different tests.

Do somebody seen anything like that?